# Delay between setexpresscheckout and doexpresscheckout

Tags: express-checkout

OK had a look through can't quite get and answer.

If a send a setexpresscheckout then the shopper get redirect and authenticates.

How long can I wait to send the doexpresscheckout? Can I wait 365 days before sending?

Do I even need to send it. Can I just use the setexpresscheckout to authenticate the shopper?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setexpresscheckout returns token.

Life time for this token - some as 3 hours or something like that...

So you can't keep this token and use after 365 days )

If you can authenticate shopper by token? Theoretically - yes, its unique value. But this absolutely not right.

The right way - authenticate shopper by more standard way and after this refer shopper and token.